# Is there other unknown-compound in Blood?

Tags: human-biology, molecular-biology, hematology

Blood is made of red blood cells, platelets, plasma etc. Let's say, then, there are these $x$ known compounds in blood.
But how can one be *sure* that there is no other compound other than those $x$ compounds? Does present technology ensure that there is no other unknown compound in blood that can't be detected?

Comment: @user1136  so, there is a probability that we don't know all the elements of blood, yet, right?

Comment: It all comes down to our ability to detect materials in blood. It would be impossible to rule out the existence of substances below the limit of detection, but would these materials have any significant effect at such low concentrations?

Comment: You might be interested in reading about proteomics and metabolomics. Both approaches are  capable of untargeted detection and identification of proteins or small molecules, respectively.